# FreeBSD rc.d mysqlcheck run at startup

Tags: freebsd, autorun

I have the following script in my  /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysqlcheck

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/rc.subr

name=mysqlcheck
rcvar=`set_rcvar`

command=/usr/local/bin/mysqlcheck
command_args=" -c -u root --all-databases >> /usr/home/user/rebooted.txt" # just to know if it works

pidfile="/var/run/${name}.pid"

sig_reload="USR1"

load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

In my /etc/rc.conf I have line like

```
mysqlcheck_enable="yes"
```

I can run that script from command line

```
#sevice mysqlcheck start
```

But it doesn't run at server startup

What is wrong with my script or config?

Maybe mysqlcheck runs before mysql-server? How can I force mycqlcheck force to start after mysql-server? Who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing rcvar=set_rcvar to rcvar=${name}_enable or even just rcvar=mysqlcheck_enable

then add the following at the top of the file after the `#!/bin/sh`:

```
# PROVIDE: mysqlcheck
# REQUIRE: DAEMON mysql
# BEFORE: LOGIN
# KEYWORD: shutdown
```

Further documentation can be [found here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/rc-scripting/rcng-hookup.html).

Comment: unfortunately it still doesnt run at startup (no changes in /usr/home/user/rebooted.txt). But it still runs manually.

Comment: And the permissions on the file are correct? root:wheel with chmod 555?

Comment: Permissions are: root@freebsd2:~ # ls -l /usr/local/etc/rc.d/
total 8
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  2187 Oct 31 07:44 mysql-server
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   279 Nov 14 17:10 mysqlcheck
But script doesnt run on startup

Comment: Add the following to your script, just after the #!/bin/sh
    `# PROVIDE: mysqlcheck  
    # REQUIRE: DAEMON mysql  
    # BEFORE: LOGIN  
    # KEYWORD: shutdown`

Each on their own line, my comment formatting is fail.

Comment: thank you. I added # REQUIRE: mysql and it works now